# Retrieving the last record in each group - Error

Tags: postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

In reference to the post "[Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)", I adapted my query (using postgresql) to look for the last object of **MATABLE** on the zone **MAZONE** whose attribute **created_at** is the most recent:

```
SELECT 
  p1.id, 
  p2.id 
FROM MATABLE p1 
  LEFT JOIN MATABLE p2 
    ON (p1.zone_id = p2.zone_id AND p1.created_at < p2.created_at) 
WHERE 
  p2.id IS NULL 
  AND p1.zone_id = 'MAZONE';
```

The problem is that I get the following response:

```
id  | id 
----+----
(0 rows)
```

However, if I filter my table like this:

```
SELECT 
  p1.id, 
  p2.id 
FROM MATABLE p1 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM MATABLE WHERE zone_id='MAZONE') p2 
    ON (p1.zone_id = p2.zone_id AND p1.created_at < p2.created_at) 
WHERE 
  p2.id IS NULL 
  AND p1.zone_id = 'MAZONE';
```

I get a result:

```
id    | id 
------+----
12716 |   
(1 row)
```

Any idea about this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At first glance, the two queries look the same. Please, provide your schema definition and test data.

Comment: MATABLE(id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR, zone_id VARCHAR NOT NULL, created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL)

I have a ten thousand rows in this table, maybe it has an impact on the query...